# How can I swap the text inside html button, using a js function with id parameter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to swap the text inside a html button, but using a function with 3 parameters, id, first_text, second_text.

I was looking on another questions with the same problem, but it won't help me.

This is not working:

Button(var1,value,id are variables from php):
         `<input type='button' id=".$id." onclick='swaptxt('"$.id."', '".$var1."','".$value."')' value=".$value.">`

Function:

```
function swaptxt(index, text1, text2){
        var elem = document.getElementById(index);
        if (elem.value===text1)
          elem.value = text2;
        else
          elem.value = text1;
```

Comment: should be: `onclick="swaptxt(...)"`

Comment: quotes missing for function - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/jONyXQd

Comment: still not working, the full code has echo before, and all " should be '. But still not working. @NagaSaiA

Comment: update quotes , i think you are using mix of single and double quotes which is causing issue

Comment: quotes updated @NagaSaiA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't echo it from PHP, just drop out of PHP and only use PHP to add the variables.

```
?> <!-- we are no longer in PHP -->
<input type='button' id='<?php echo $id;    ?>' 
       onclick='swaptxt('<?php echo $id;    ?>', 
                        '<?php echo $var1;  ?>',
                        '<?php echo $value; ?>')' 
       value='<?php echo $value; ?>'>
<?php // back to PHP now
```

Comment: I can't do this because the entire echo is in a big php function.

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference. You may drop in and out of PHP at will whether you are in a function or not.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

You are not getting the correct output because you are passing the wrong id in argument. In input, you have given id as "**.$id.**" but in the argument, you are passing the id as "**$.id.**". Provide the correct id and you will get your expected output.

```js
function swaptxt(index, text1, text2){
  var elem = document.getElementById(index);
  if (elem.value===text1)
    elem.value = text2;
  else
    elem.value = text1;
}
```

```html
<input type='button' id=".$id." onclick='swaptxt(".$id.",".$value.", ".$var1.")' value=".$value">
```

Answer (score 0):

another way to concat it:

```
onclick="swaptxt(\'' . $id . '\',\'' . $var1 . '\',\'' . $value .'\');"
```